# Visitors who visited /page1 and also /page2

Tags: awk, grep, apache-httpd, logs, apache-virtualhost

In my Apache log file `other_vhosts_access.log` that looks like this:

```
www.example.com:80 12.34.56.78 - - [01/Aug/2017:00:42:18 +0200] "GET /page1.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1542 " "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
www.example.com:80 99.99.99.99 - - [02/Aug/2017:06:19:44 +0200] "GET /test.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 90749 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
www.anotherwebsite.com:80 11.11.11.11 - - [04/Aug/2017:09:39:01 +0200] "GET /test.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 90749 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"

...
www.example.com:80 12.34.56.78 - - [23/Aug/2017:01:12:11 +0200] "GET /somethingelse2.html HTTP/1.1" 200 21161 "http://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
```

I'd like to find visitors who visited `/page1.html` **and** `/somethingelse2.html`, here in the example: 12.34.56.78.

If I use:

```
grep page1.html other_vhosts_access.log
```

I cannot filter the output anymore, because the remaining lines don't include `somethingelse2.html`.

**How to find visitors who visited one specific page + another one?**

Comment: I noticed you included various domains in the log; does that matter?

Comment: Yes and no :) I explain: all the virtual hosts are logged in the same log file that's why the first column is `www.example.com` (default Ubuntu config). But in my use case page1.html and somethingelse2.html are specific names that can be found only in *one* of the virtual hosts, so finally it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash`, `grep` and `awk`:

This is how you get all the IP numbers correlating with the `page1.html` file:

```
awk '/page1\.html/ { print $2 }' log
```

For the example data, this will output `12.34.56.78`.

This may be used to get all the log entries that contain that IP address:

```
grep -wF -f <( awk '/page1\.html/ { print $2 }' log ) log
```

This uses the result of the `awk` command as a pattern and scans the logfile a second time to output all the lines that contains that IP. This returns the first and last line from the example.

The `-w` and `-F` flag to `grep` are used to tell `grep` to interpret the pattern (IP address) as a *fixed string* (`-F`) and to only return lines that contains that string as a *whole word* (`-w`).  This means `12.34.56.789` will not be matched by the fixed string pattern `12.34.56.78`.

From that result, we may *remove* the lines that is about `page1.html` with

```
grep -wF -f <( awk '/page1\.html/ { print $2 }' log ) log | grep -vF 'page1.html'
```

Now you have all log entries produced by visitors to the `page1.html` page (but not including the `page1.html` page itself).

If you want to get the entries for a *particular* other page, then change the last `grep -vF 'page1.html'` to `grep -F 'otherpage.html'`.

---

I'm pretty sure there are more robust log parsing and analyzing tool out there, but if there are, I don't know about them (I don't do log parsing very often).

Comment: That's a wonderful answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is done in awk using associative arrays to remember what has already been seen in the input. Using the default awk whitespace field separator, we note that field 2 is the ip address, and field 8 is the url, so for example,

```
awk '$8=="/page1.html"          { ipaddr[$2] = 1; next }
     $8=="/somethingelse2.html" { if(ipaddr[$2]==1)print $2 }'
```

This will compare the url field and when it matches the first url it creates an entry in array `ipaddr` for the ip address, to hold value 1. When it matches the second url it checks if we have set the entry for the same ip address, and if so prints it. To avoid reprinting the same ip address we could note it in another array:

```
awk '$8=="/page1.html"          { ipaddr[$2] = 1; next }
     $8=="/somethingelse2.html" { if(ipaddr[$2]==1 && !done[$2]){print $2; done[$2]=1 } }'
```

If the url might have a query part (eg `"/page1.html?id=77"`), you can use matches instead of comparisons, ie `$8~/^\/page1.html/`.

If the urls might be visited in reverse order, you can use a bitmask value to remember which one you have already seen, eg 1 for page1 and 2 for somethingelse2, and then wait until you have the value 3. Bitmasks are available in awk only through functions like `or` and `and`.  So we might have

```
awk '
BEGIN { v["/page1.html"] = 1
        v["/somethingelse2.html"] = 2
}
$8=="/page1.html" || $8=="/somethingelse2.html"  {
  ipaddr[$2] = or(ipaddr[$2], v[$8])
  if(ipaddr[$2]==3){ print $2; ipaddr[$2] = 4 }
}'
```

This sets up, in the BEGIN block done once at the start, a mapping in associative array `v` to convert the url to our bitmask value (just an integer).
When either url is matched, the remembered value has the appropriate bitmask value or-ed in. If it is now 3, we print the address, and set it so that it will not be printed again.

Comment: +1 Nice "awk" style with associative arrays and bitmask. This is also the better parsing solution. Thanks _meuh_.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the format of other_vhosts_access.log is richer than you care for, in this task. I recommend you pick out a few of your favorite columns, e.g. `awk '{print $2, $8}' other_vhosts_access.log > small.log`, and then manipulate small.log, which you can eyeball more conveniently.

The trouble is explained on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html:

> ... commonly used format string is called the Combined Log Format. It can be used as follows.
>   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{**Referer**}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined

That appears to be what you're using. You quoted `example.com` in your (sanitized) log, indicating that a site like example.com had an HREF to your site, and a browser included a "Referer: www.example.com" header in their GET request.

It seems very very likely that /page1 has HREFs to /page2. Some browsers will send a page1 referer header on page2 requests. You could choose to rely on this, and grep for 'page2.*page1'. Or you could choose to rely on source IP as in the accepted answer. In that case you probably want to strip out other distracting columns that will cause false matches, and use a simplified small.log for your analyses.

Comment: Thanks but it's not possible to use referer. I want to count a user that comes to visit page1 on one day, and comes back to visit the other page two days after. In this case no referrer will be directly logged.

Comment: Oh, sure. (For some folks the sequence takes 2 minutes, for others 2 days). That's cool. My point was that if you choose to focus on essentially two columns of the log (ip & url), then having more than 3 columns (ip, url, referer) in your `grep` analysis will confound things. Better to simplify, so the results you view correspond to what you had in mind, without 3rd column artifacts.